# Errors request.CRITICAL and security.INFO in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: security, request, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

When entering the admin panel and navigation, an HTTP ERROR 500 or just a blank screen occurs.
If a `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);` then everything works without problems.
 In `prod.log` such errors:

```html
[2019-02-08 18:54:05] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Twig_Error_Loader: Template "@Twig/Exception/error.html.twig" is not defined. at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php line 129) {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): Template \"@Twig/Exception/error.html.twig\" is not defined. at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php:129)"} []
[2019-02-08 18:54:31] request.INFO: Matched route "admin_module_manage". {"route":"admin_module_manage","route_parameters":{"category":null,"keyword":null,"_controller":"PrestaShopBundle\\Controller\\Admin\\Improve\\ModuleController::manageAction","_legacy_controller":"AdminModulesManage","_legacy_link":["AdminModulesManage","AdminModulesSf"],"_route":"admin_module_manage"},"request_uri":"https://example.com/backend/index.php/improve/modules/manage?_token=dWJPi1JOoGAUmEV8zKGYaGH8QFbBHa9Iq0KsRcJp4zM","method":"GET"} []
[2019-02-08 18:54:31] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2019-02-08 18:54:31] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Loader: "The "/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product" directory does not exist ("/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product")." at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 101 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): The \"/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product\" directory does not exist (\"/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product\"). at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:101)"} []
[2019-02-08 18:54:31] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Twig_Error_Loader: Template "@Twig/Exception/error.html.twig" is not defined. at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php line 129) {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): Template \"@Twig/Exception/error.html.twig\" is not defined. at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php:129)"} []
[2019-02-08 18:59:22] request.INFO: Matched route "admin_module_manage". {"route":"admin_module_manage","route_parameters":{"category":null,"keyword":null,"_controller":"PrestaShopBundle\\Controller\\Admin\\Improve\\ModuleController::manageAction","_legacy_controller":"AdminModulesManage","_legacy_link":["AdminModulesManage","AdminModulesSf"],"_route":"admin_module_manage"},"request_uri":"https://example.com/backend/index.php/improve/modules/manage?_token=lsKOK99JQWUUwmiA8feoUvqcYs80of6K5ora0Mop7sU","method":"GET"} []
[2019-02-08 18:59:23] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2019-02-08 18:59:23] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Loader: "The "/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product" directory does not exist ("/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product")." at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 101 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): The \"/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product\" directory does not exist (\"/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product\"). at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:101)"} []
[2019-02-08 18:59:23] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Twig_Error_Loader: Template "@Twig/Exception/error.html.twig" is not defined. at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php line 129) {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): Template \"@Twig/Exception/error.html.twig\" is not defined. at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php:129)"} []
[2019-02-08 18:59:31] request.INFO: Matched route "admin_module_manage". {"route":"admin_module_manage","route_parameters":{"category":null,"keyword":null,"_controller":"PrestaShopBundle\\Controller\\Admin\\Improve\\ModuleController::manageAction","_legacy_controller":"AdminModulesManage","_legacy_link":["AdminModulesManage","AdminModulesSf"],"_route":"admin_module_manage"},"request_uri":"https://example.com/backend/index.php/improve/modules/manage?_token=lsKOK99JQWUUwmiA8feoUvqcYs80of6K5ora0Mop7sU","method":"GET"} []
[2019-02-08 18:59:31] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2019-02-08 18:59:31] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Loader: "The "/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product" directory does not exist ("/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product")." at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 101 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): The \"/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product\" directory does not exist (\"/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html\\app/../src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product\"). at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:101)"} []
[2019-02-08 18:59:31] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Twig_Error_Loader: Template "@Twig/Exception/error.html.twig" is not defined. at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php line 129) {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): Template \"@Twig/Exception/error.html.twig\" is not defined. at /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/modules/autoupgrade/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php:129)"} []
```

Tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem by deleting the contents of the folder `/var/cache/dev/Container`

Comment: Great! It helpd me too! Thank

Answer (score 0):

seems like compile errors, try to remove var/cache/prod/class_index.php and maybe var/cache/dev/class_index.php

Comment: Removed, did not help